# Is an indignant or surprised question a rhetoric question?

Tags: questions, rhetoric

Learn to Read Latin says on p115

> an (conj.) *introduces an indignant or surprised question expecting a negative answer.* can it really be that ...

Althought it is about Latin, it is also about English if we only look at the meaning of "an" is "can it really be that ...".

Is an indignant or surprised question a rhetoric question?

By definition, a rhetoric question expect no answer from the audience, and an indignant or surprised question can expect a negative answer. Are they essentially the same, because they are both used by the speaker to indicate they have already known the answer?

Comment: Indignation and surprise are simply emotions. They can fuel many kinds of utterances, including questions that expect positive *or* negative answers. "What? You're really going to marry him?" OR "What? You're not going to marry him, are you?" And *both* questions could truly expect an answer, or could just be expressing outrage/shock; the tone and context would decide.

Answer (score 4):

A rhetorical question is inserted intentionally to prove a point, the answer of which is obvious, e.g., "Do you *really* believe Novalny died of natural causes?" There is no element of surprise in that question; it is the *opposite*, stated to *affirm* a viewpoint.

One *might* ask a question indignantly, or in surprise, that is rhetorical, but they're not synonymous. "Did you really think I'd be late?" could be both rhetorical *and* asked in surprise. "You don't want ice cream?" might be asked in surprise, but is just looking for confirmation of an odd statement (Who would *not* want ice cream?)

Answer (score 2):

There is no grammar of rhetorical questions.  The question "Is it a cat?" might be a rhetorical question, or it might not. It depends entirely on the *intent* of the speaker

To give an example: a question, "Can it be that [you are an adult]?"  might be a rhetorical question. The speaker is expressing surprise that someone is an adult. Or it might be a genuine question, the speaker is surprised and wants an an affirmation or denial.

So, unless you know the intent of the speaker, which you might be able to infer from context, it is impossible to know if a question is rhetorical or not.

Answer (score 2):

**Can it be that ...?** could indeed be a rhetorical question in context.

> The other side of the aisle have not offered an alternative. Can it be they have no real plan to solve the crisis, and merely wish to prolong it in order to use it to cudgel us come election time?

To ask "is it possible" when you clearly think it is not only possible but highly probable or even definite, is to *feign* surprise.